Why can't I launch a Django project in Kubernetes?
Good afternoon, I ran into the problem that it is not possible to launch a Django project inside kybernetike.
I have a deployment for the project.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: django-cloud-todo-list-svc
  labels:
    app: django-cloud-todo-list
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  type: LoadBalancer

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: django-cloud-todo-list
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: django-cloud-todo-list
      tier: app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: django-cloud-todo-list
        tier: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: django-cloud-todo-list
          image: trickstermaster/cloud-todo-list-django_web:18.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000

Everything starts successfully
root@main-serv:/home/main-serv/k3s/deployment/cloud-todo-list-django_web# kubectl get pod
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
django-cloud-todo-list-7fb9bbfcc6-r5zm6   1/1     Running   0          38m

root@main-serv:/home/main-serv/k3s/deployment/cloud-todo-list-django_web# kubectl get svc
NAME                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
django-cloud-todo-list-svc   LoadBalancer   10.43.186.41   192.168.0.176   8000:31806/TCP   38m

But when you try to open the page, nothing works, everything is fine inside the pod
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  41m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/django-cloud-todo-list-7fb9bbfcc6-r5zm6 to k3s-master-1
  Normal  Pulled     41m   kubelet            Container image "trickstermaster/cloud-todo-list-django_web:18.0" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    41m   kubelet            Created container django-cloud-todo-list
  Normal  Started    41m   kubelet            Started container django-cloud-todo-list

LoadBalancer is working properly, because all other projects are working properly.
Image is also working properly, if you use it in docker-compose, everything rises calmly.
version: '3.5'
services:
  web-server:
    image: trickstermaster/cloud-todo-list-django_web:18.0
    container_name: test
    ports:
      - '9000:8000'


Have you looked at the logging? Anything to indicate the app is fully up or traffic successfully getting through the loadbalancer and being received at the app?

the problem was in the deployment file

I redid my deployment file, and everything started
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: django-cloud-todo-list-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: django-cloud-todo-list
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: django-cloud-todo-list
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: django-cloud-todo-list
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: django-cloud-todo-list
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: django-cloud-todo-list
        image: trickstermaster/cloud-todo-list-django_web:18.0
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
        imagePullPolicy: Always


Please elaborate on the change that resolved the issue
